# Create numpy array reusing memory of other array

Tags: python, numpy, memory-management

I have following code:

```
a = np.zeros(N)
b = np.tile(a, [m, n])

....

a[4] = 5 # just changing some values inside a
b = np.tile(a, [m, n])
```

In the second assignment for `b`, can the previous memory of `b` be overwritten during this procedure instead of creating a new array then assigning to `b`? I understand that memory of previous `b` will be garbage collected soon afterwards but I want to implement it in more performant way since `N`, `m`, `n` can be large in my use case.

Comment: `b[:]=np.tile(...)` may work.  But it will still make a new temporary RHS array before the LHS assignment.  So it won't be faster.  I don't think `tile` takes an `out` parameter.  Tile is repeated `repeat`, which expects to return a new larger array.

Comment: unless you get memory errors, trying to be 'performant' by fine tuning memory use is usually not worth the effort.

Comment: It is possible to reshape and broadcast assignment, but this is unreadable and only slightly faster than tile for large array: `b.reshape(-1, a.size)[:] = a`

Answer (score 0):

You need to force the de-allocation of `b` first:

```py
a = np.zeros(N)
b = np.tile(a, [m, n])

....

a[4] = 5 # just changing some values inside a
import gc #import garbage collect interface
del b
gc.collect() #makes sure the memory referenced by b is freed if still not done
b = np.tile(a, [m, n])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably less efficient, but you could write a `tile` function to work in-place, e.g.:

```py
import numpy as 

def tile_inplace(a, B):
    """
    Place a into B.
    """

    la = len(a)
    bv = B.reshape(-1)  # get flattened view of the array

    for i in range(len(bv) // la):
        bv[i * la: (i + 1) * la] = a

    return B


a = np.zeros(N)
b = np.tile(a, [m, n])

a[4] = 5
b = tile_inplace(a, b)
```